# Mongodb query.update method does not update array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, promise

Previously I had tried something like (with mongoose and promises):

`var cursor = User.find({email: from.address, token: tokenMatches[1]});`
and then

```
return cursor.update(
    {'votes.title': b},
    {'$set': { 'votes.$.category': a }}
).then(function (result) {
    if(result.nModified == 0) {
        return cursor.update({}, {'$push': { votes: { category: a, title: b }}}).then(function (res) {
            ServerLog('updatePush', res);
            return res;
        });
    }
});
```

But it always returned nModified = 0 for the first and second call. Until I found out that the cursor object actually has no update function. So why is it so? And why did it not throw an exception?

Answer (score 2):

[`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) returns a [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object, not a cursor. `Query` *does* have an [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) method that lets you execute the query as an update operation.

Comment: Ok, so it actually should work. What confuses me is that the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) define the update method as: `Query#update([criteria], [doc], [options], [callback])` but then sometimes use it without the criteria and directly pass the doc: `Model.where({ _id: id }).update({ title: 'words' })`

Comment: @velop The update will use the query criteria already added to the `Query` (e.g. from the `where` call in your example) if you don't provide it in the `update` call itself.